# How to get started?

Tags: beginner

I am currently working as a registered nurse, but I have decided that I can no longer do this as a career. I was essentially forced by my parents to go into the health field. After doing research on many career fields, I believe that a career as a data scientist is a career that I would enjoy and be satisfied in. The only problem is that I don’t know how to get started. I have a bachelor’s degree in biology apart from my nursing degree. I’m tnis degree program, I had to take college level calculus, prob&stats, algebra, etc.  To get to my point, should I go back to school to obtain a degree in statistics or CS, or should I train on my own to learn the skill necessary for the job?  I am very disciplined when it comes to education, so self- teaching would not be an issue on my end. Any advice would be very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry it is not really possible to give career advice or create a learning plan for you on this site. In terms of learning, you could take a look at some MOOCs - Andrew Ng's introductory course on Coursera might be a good way to check out more of the subject area and decide it you are still interested - https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning -  although that depends on how comfortable you would be learning to program in Matlab (or Octave) to tackle it (some introductory programming material is part of the course).

Comment: If you did not take a class in data structures and algorithms at school, take a MOOC in that before doing Andrew Ng's ML MOOC so you have a stronger foundation on the software side. I recommend this one: [Algorithms I](https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithms-part1), [Algorithms II](https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithms-part2).

Comment: Thank you all for the advice and insight you have given. I have recently enrolled into a data analytics masters degree program. Do you think this along with self teaching the programming (R and Python) would put me in a good spot to start my career?

Answer (score 2):

Congrats on your career move, but please know that data science is one of the more difficult fields to enter, being a combination of statistics, programming, computer science, mathematics, etc. But, for someone motivated enough, with sharp acumen and intuitive data skills, it's a great field. A commenter recommended Andrew Ng's (pronounced 'ing' ) online course through coursera, and I also agree this is a great foundation.  It is dense, but you'll need to master it if you hope to be a quality data scientist. He uses Octave, but I advise that you come up to speed quickly in R or Python. If you can translate Andy's code to either of those platforms, you'll be in good shape to start your practice.

Comment: Thank you all for the advice and insight you have given. I have recently enrolled into a data analytics masters degree program. Do you think this along with self teaching the programming (R and Python) would put me in a good spot to start my career?

Comment: I would try to do an internship. Degrees are good but showing practical knowledge is really important. There's a lot of people calling themselves data scientists these days but few actually are.